# Binding FontSize of TextBlock in Validation.ErrorTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, errortemplate

I declared a simple Validation.ErrorTemplate for TextBox as the following.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="!" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding TextBox.FontSize}" 
                               Foreground="Red"/>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder  Name="adornerPlaceholder" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I expect that the font size of the exclamation mark will be the same **font(edited)** size as TextBox, but it doesn't result in the expectation and always gets the default font size. Furthermore, I tried Binding using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=FontSize`, but it also cannot solve the problem. Why is this situation occurred? How can I make the the exclamation mark gets the same size as TextBox?

Comment: Your questing is a little ambiguous.  Are you trying to bind to a font-size that is applied to the text box or are you trying to bind to the size of the text box? If the former did you apply a different font size to the text box?

Comment: @CBRRacer: This question is not the both you mentioned. I intend that when text of `TextBox` is invalid, a exclamation mark appears right to the TextBox and the font size of the exclamation mark gets the same font size as the TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you bind to the `AdornedElementPlaceholder`?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="!" DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                           FontSize="{Binding ElementName=adornerPlaceholder, Path=AdornedElement.FontSize}" 
                           Foreground="Red"/>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder  Name="adornerPlaceholder" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

This is untested, but it should work :)

Comment: I see that there is the easy way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to wrap the `TextBlock` in a `Viewbox`, which automatically scales its height along with the adorned element:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Viewbox DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=adornerPlaceholder, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                        Stretch="Uniform"
                        Margin="5 0">
                        <TextBlock Text="!" Foreground="Red" />
                    </Viewbox>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adornerPlaceholder" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This would then work for any element being adorned, regardless of font size, any for any exclamation graphic (i.e. text, path, element, etc)

Positioning/layout can be tweaked with margin.